# remove fragment in viewPager2 and FragmentStateAdapter is not working

Tags: android-fragments, android-adapter, android-viewpager2

I've 3 Fragment - F1, F2, and F3. I've attached them in a PagerAdaper (viewPager2). The initialization of the PagerAdapter in PagerFragment (in onCreateView) is -

```
binding = PagerFargmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
adapter = PagerAdapter(this)
binding?.viewPager?.adapter = adapter
binding?.viewPager?.isSaveEnabled = false
```

Now, My PagerAdapter Implementation -->

```
class PagerAdapter(
    fragment: PagerFragment,
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

    private var nextFragment: BaseFragment? = null
    private var baseFragment: BaseFragment = F1()

    override fun getItemCount() = 2

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    
        return when (position) {
            0 -> {
                baseFragment
            }
            else -> {
                nextFragment ?: DummyDialogFragment()
            }
        }
    }

    fun setNextFragment(page: Int) {
        nextFragment = null
        nextFragment = if (page == 1) {
            F2()
        } else if (page == 2) {
            F3()
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
 }
```

Now From my Pager Fragment I'm setting the next fragment -

```
fun navigateTo(page: Int) {
    adapter.setNextFragment(page)
    if (page == 0) {
        binding?.viewPager?.currentItem = page
    } else {
        binding?.viewPager?.currentItem = 1
    }
}
```

*And From F1 fragment I'm calling this function with 1 and 2. This is working fine for the first time.*
**If First time, If I load F2 fragment as a nextFragment then F3 fragment is not displaying.** *I've tried debugging and found out that the nextFragment value is updating but somehow the added fragment is not being removed from the pager Adapter.*

**Is there any way so that I can add / remove fragment dynamically?**

*I've taken implementation idea from this block - https://intensecoder.com/android-swipe-fragments-with-viewpager2-in-kotlin/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after quite a bit of exploring over stackoverflow and then the help of one of my peer, I've figure out the solution. The solution is -

> Actually the problem was, the createFragment() was not triggering
> after the first time. So I've to override two function of
> StatePagerAdapter - getItemViewType() and getItemId(). My Implementation
> now -

```
class PagerAdapter(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {

    private var viewType: Int = 0

    override fun getItemCount() = 2

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> {
                F1()
            }
            1 -> {
                F2()
            }
            else -> {
                F3()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> 0
            else -> viewType
        }
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> 0
            else -> viewType.toLong()
        }
    }

    fun setNextFragment(page: Int) {
        this.viewType = page
    }
 }
```

and Calling this from pagger fragment -

```
fun navigateTo(page: Int) {
    adapter.setNextFragment(page)
    if (page == 0) {
        binding?.viewPager?.currentItem = page
    } else {
        binding?.viewPager?.currentItem = 1
    }
}
```

The setNextFragment() assigning the desired F2() or F3() fragment. And by the help of the override implementation on getItemId() and getItemViewType() the createFragment() is getting called each time and thus I can add / remove fragment dynamically.